# ¿Cómo puedo obtener una lista de listas de un promedio recursivamente en haskell si su tipo es promedios :: Fractional a => [[a]] -> [a]?

Tags: lista, haskell

necesito saber como hago en haskell para sacar recursivamente el promedio de una lista de listas, que me devuelva la lista de los promedios de cada lista-elemento, es decir que si tengo [[2,6],[9,9,2,4],[10,2,6]] me devuelve [4,6,6]. Lo que pude hacer no me sirve porque ahora me piden que promedios sea declarado recursivamente y ahí es donde empieza mi problema. Gracias!

```
promedios :: Fractional a => [[a]] -> [a]
promedios xss = map promedio xss
  where
    promedio [] = 0
    promedio xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Es muy importante que agregues el codigo que llevas.

Comment: Por la pregunta supongo que esto es una tarea o trabajo de clase, ¿no? Me parece genial que ahora enseñen Haskell. ¿En qué escuela o universidad lo están enseñando?

Answer (score 0):

Tu versión usando `map` es perfectamente válida. Supongo que te piden que la hagas de modo recursiva para que aprendas.

En una función recursiva, la definición de la función tiene que invocarse a sí misma, con un caso base para cortar la recursividad.

Podemos hacerlo así:

```
promedios :: Fractional a => [[a]] -> [a]
promedios [] = []
promedios (xs:xss) = promedio xs : promedios xss
  where
    promedio [] = 0
    promedio ys = sum ys / (fromIntegral (length ys))
```

En general:

```
map f xs
```

se puede expresar como

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

Comment: Me sirvió para comprender la recursión, aunque me dijeron que aún no use **where**  porque no lo aprendimos. lo tuve que modificar en un mínimo para que me compile.

`promedios [] = []

promedios (xs:xss) = promedio xs : promedios xss
  where
    promedio [] = 0
    
    promedio ys = sum ys `div` length ys`

Comment: Ojo, que en la signatura de `promedios` pones `Fractional`, sin embargo `div` es para `Integral`. He cambiado el código para que compile.